# Is it possible to order an array alphabetically in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, alphabetical-sort

I am new to Laravel and I was wondering if I can order the following multidimensional array with countries alphabetically? So I want all the countries inside the continents to be ordered alphabetically.

```
  "EU" => array:9 
    0 => "NL"
    1 => "BE"
    3 => "FR"
    4 => "DE"
    5 => "ES"
    6 => "IT"
    7 => "GB"
    8 => "TR"
    9 => "DK"
  ]
  "AS" => array:2
]
```

Comment: Related: [Sort data in column of a multi-dimensional array in a descending direction while preserving keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74635226/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to sort an inner array by values. Here is a one way to do it.

```
$arr = [
   "EU" => [
        0 => "NL",
        1 => "BE",
        3 => "FR",
        4 => "DE",
        5 => "ES",
        6 => "IT",
        7 => "GB",
        8 => "TR",
        9 => "DK",
  ],
  "AS" => ["AB", "AA"]
];

foreach($arr as $continent => $countries) {
    asort($countries);
    $arr[$continent] = $countries;
}


var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Can I also remove the duplicate countries in that foreach?

Comment: @Elisaveta sure you can!. You need to change this line `$arr[$continent] = $countries;`
to this `$arr[$continent] = array_unique($countries)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a Laravel answer, you might be interested in [the `Arr::sortRecursive()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-array-sort-recursive) for a short and fluent implementation. Let me demonstrate the code for your data while also expending your data a bit more to the my point across.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$array = [
  "EU" => [
    "NL", "BE", "FR", "DE", "ES", "IT", "GB", "TR", "DK",
  ],
  "AS" => [
    "JA", "IN", "CH",
  ],
  "NA" => [
    "US", "ME", "CA",
  ],
];
 
$sorted = Arr::sortRecursive($array);

/*
[
  "AS" => [
    "CH", "IN", "JA",
  ],
  "EU" => [
    "BE", "DE", "DK", "ES", "FR", "GB", "IT", "NL", "TR",
  ],
  "NA" => [
    "CA", "ME", "US",
  ],
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input array is an associative array of associative arrays (has a consistent depth of 2 levels) therefore recursion is not necessary.

Use a classic loop or functional iterator (like `array_walk()`), modify the rows by reference and call `sort()`.  Judging by your comment under another answer, you need to call `array_unique()` on each row as well -- to remove duplicate values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6EsCn))

```
foreach ($arr as &$row) {
    sort($row);
}
var_export($arr);
```

For functional-style programming, `array_walk()` can sort the rows concisely. I've left out the duplicate removal call. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nudUS))

```
array_walk($arr, fn(&$row) => sort($row));
var_export($arr);
```

Comment: (Surely this is a duplicate question, but I couldn't find one ...and I even did a SEDE search.  I must be using the wrong keywords.)

Answer (score -1):

Laravel has nothing to do with these stuff. You should use PHP functions and here's an example:

```php
$arr = [
    0 => "NL",
    1 => "BE",
    3 => "FR",
    4 => "DE",
    5 => "ES",
    6 => "IT",
    7 => "GB",
    8 => "TR",
    9 => "DK",
];

sort($arr);

print_r($arr);
```

The result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => BE
    [1] => DE
    [2] => DK
    [3] => ES
    [4] => FR
    [5] => GB
    [6] => IT
    [7] => NL
    [8] => TR
)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this does not work as it is multidimensional array.

Comment: What about using `usort` function? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Still does not work, I already tried those options

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what input you have, and what output you want. This is how we can help you better.