# Sort data in column of a multi-dimensional array in a descending direction while preserving keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, sub-array

I have the following array that I'm attempting to sort each `scores` array by `answer` from high to low.

```
$array = [
    503 => [
        'scores' => [
            4573 => ['answer' => 100],
            4574 => ['answer' => 60],
            4575 => ['answer' => 100],
            4576 => ['answer' => 80],
            4577 => ['answer' => 40],
            4578 => ['answer' => 20],
            4579 => ['answer' => 60],
            4580 => ['answer' => 100],
            4581 => ['answer' => 60],
            4582 => ['answer' => 60],
            4583 => ['answer' => 80],
            4584 => ['answer' => 80],
        ],
        'category' => 'Category A',
        'grade' => 70,
        'color' => NULL
    ],
    504 => [
        'scores' => [
            4585 => ['answer' => 40],
            4586 => ['answer' => 100],
            4587 => ['answer' => 80],
            4588 => ['answer' => 60],
            4589 => ['answer' => 100],
            4590 => ['answer' => 40],
            4591 => ['answer' => 80],
            4592 => ['answer' => 60],
            4593 => ['answer' => 60],
            4594 => ['answer' => 100],
            4595 => ['answer' => 100],
            4596 => ['answer' => 80], 
        ],
        'category' => 'Category B',
        'grade' => 75,
        'color' => NULL
    ],
    505 => [
        'scores' => [
            4597 =>['answer' => 20],
            4598 =>['answer' => 80],
            4599 =>['answer' => 100],
            4600 =>['answer' => 60],
            4601 =>['answer' => 20],
            4602 =>['answer' => 20],
            4603 =>['answer' => 100],
            4604 =>['answer' => 40],
            4605 =>['answer' => 60],
            4606 =>['answer' => 100],
            4607 =>['answer' => 80],
            4608 =>['answer' => 20],
        ],
        'category' => 'Category C',
        'grade' => 58.3,
        'color' => NULL, 
    ]
];
```

I've attempted to use loops to get into the array level needed, but it isn't working...

```
$temp_array_questions = $array_categorygrades;
function sortq ($a, $b) {
    $highestcountfora = 0;
    $highestcountforb = 0;
    
    foreach ($a as $thescores) {
        if (is_array($thescores)) {
            foreach ($thescores as $thequestions) {
                if (is_array($thequestions)) {
                    foreach ($thequestions as $theanswers) {
                        if ($theanswers['answer'] > $highestcountfora) {
                            $highestcountfora = $theanswers['answer'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    foreach ($b as $thescores) {
        if (is_array($thescores)) {
            foreach ($thescores as $thequestions) {
                if (is_array($thequestions)) {
                    foreach ($thequestions as $theanswers) {
                        if ($theanswers['answer'] > $highestcountforb) {
                            $highestcountforb = $theanswers['answer'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    if ($highestcountfora === $highestcountforb) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    return ($highestcountfora < $highestcountforb)?1:-1;
    
    //if($a['scores']['answer']==$b['scores']['answer']) return 0;
    //return $a['scores']['answer'] < $b['scores']['answer']?1:-1;
} 
uasort($temp_array_questions, 'sortq');
```

The array should look like this after sorting (keeping the top-level categories intact):

```
[
    503 => [
        'scores' => [
            4573 => ['answer' => 100],
            4575 => ['answer' => 100],
            4580 => ['answer' => 100],
            4576 => ['answer' => 80],
            4583 => ['answer' => 80],
            4584 => ['answer' => 80],
            4574 => ['answer' => 60],
            4579 => ['answer' => 60],
            4581 => ['answer' => 60],
            4582 => ['answer' => 60],
            4577 => ['answer' => 40],
            4578 => ['answer' => 20],
        ],
        'category' => 'Category A',
        'grade' => 70,
        'color' => NULL
    ],
    504 => [
        'scores' => [
            4586 => ['answer' => 100],
            4589 => ['answer' => 100],
            4594 => ['answer' => 100],
            4595 => ['answer' => 100],
            4587 => ['answer' => 80],
            4591 => ['answer' => 80],
            4596 => ['answer' => 80],
            4588 => ['answer' => 60],
            4592 => ['answer' => 60],
            4593 => ['answer' => 60],
            4585 => ['answer' => 40],
            4590 => ['answer' => 40],
        ],
        'category' => 'Category B',
        'grade' => 75,
        'color' => NULL
    ],
    505 => [
        'scores' => [
            4599 =>['answer' => 100],
            4603 =>['answer' => 100],
            4606 =>['answer' => 100],
            4598 =>['answer' => 80],
            4607 =>['answer' => 80],
            4600 =>['answer' => 60],
            4605 =>['answer' => 60],
            4604 =>['answer' => 40],
            4597 =>['answer' => 20],
            4601 =>['answer' => 20],
            4602 =>['answer' => 20],
            4608 =>['answer' => 20],
        ],
        'category' => 'Category C',
        'grade' => 58.3,
        'color' => NULL,
    ]
]
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us a sample expected output? Can't really tell from your describing how it should sort.

Comment: Thanks. I just added the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the `scores` subsets by their `answer` value by calling `asort()` on each subset.

I am using "array destructuring" to access only the `scores` subsets and `&` to modify the input array by reference.

You do not need to explicitly mention `answer` elements because they are lone elements in their respective subarray.  By default, PHP will sort by array size, then by values; because each subarray only has one element (size = 1), the sort will fallback to the `answer` value.

PHP7.3 and higher: ([Sort ASC Demo](https://3v4l.org/VMMu0)) ([Sort DESC Demo](https://3v4l.org/CcHA0))

```
foreach ($array as ['scores' => &$scores]) {
    arsort($scores);  // or asort($scores) for ascending sorting
}
var_export($array);
```

Or for PHP versions below 7.3: ([Sort ASC Demo](https://3v4l.org/dotOE)) ([Sort DESC Demo](https://3v4l.org/NPqOe))

```
foreach ($array as &$row) {
    arsort($row['scores']);
}
var_export($array);
```

Comment: I'm getting a fatal error when I use this... `Fatal error: [] and list() assignments cannot be by reference`

Comment: @Chris My answer is updated.

Comment: Yep. Just checked & it's outdated. But not far from your "below 7.3" solution above. I'm currently running v7.2.24. (Unfortunately, I'm not in a position to upgrade quite yet as I'd have to update quite a bit of code to avoid the app breaking.)

Comment: Thanks. I think that will work. How do I access the key for the last item in the sorted array (I'm looking for the lowest scoring answer in each category)?

Comment: For instance, if `4578 => ['answer' => 20]` is the last item/lowest score, how do I return the `4578` (which is the question ID)?

Comment: And you are ambiguously accepting the last element even if there is a tie for last?

Comment: Yes. Even if there are more than one score tied for worst, I just need the very bottom one.

Comment: You could use https://3v4l.org/Xqq5Z or https://3v4l.org/cn9Z2.  Or maybe you are confusing me and you want this: https://3v4l.org/qqIF3

Comment: Thanks. That reduces the full array to only include the lowest score. I actually just need to add the bottom scoring question_id to a new array (`4578` in the example in my comment above) so I have a simple array of the lowest scoring question IDs from all categories.

Comment: Then my final guess is to form an associative array like this: https://3v4l.org/OmOSu

Comment: Yes! That did it! I had to remove the `$id` from the brackets for it to work, but now I have a `$lowests` array with the question IDs from each category. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Ah, my earlier demo (`3v4l.org/qqIF3`) shouldn't have used `arsort()` https://3v4l.org/A25lr

Answer (score 0):

Just use usort for each individual array of scores:

```php
foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
  if (!isset($item["scores"])) continue;
 
  $scores = $item["scores"];
  usort($scores, function($a, $b) {
    return $a["answer"] - $b["answer"];
  });

  $data[$key]["scores"] = $scores;

}
```

Comment: This almost works. Unfortunately I lose the keys for each `answer` (which I need). This is my output now using your solution... `{"503":{"scores":[{"answer":100},{"answer":100},{"answer":100},{"answer":80},{"answer":80},{"answer":80},{"answer":60},{"answer":60},{"answer":60},{"answer":60},{"answer":40},{"answer":20}],"category":"Mind","grade":70,"color":null}`